# Get data from a .txt file to variable on MatLab

Tags: matlab, math

I have to do some calcs from a .txt file called star.txt:

```
Ball1   0.1001  Cube1   7
Ball2   0.1005  Cube2   10
Ball3   0.10073 Cube3   2.5
```

How can i to MatLab reads the .txt file and make each column turn to a vector , for me do some calcs?

Comment: @HosseinKa Not exactly the same.  The duplicate only has numerical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided data in your text file is properly and coherently delimited (by, for example, a whitespace character), you can use the following approach:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
data = textscan(fid,'%s %f %s %f');
fclose(fid);
```

Once your data has been read into a cell matrix, you can split it into separate vectors as follows:

```
balls = data(1,:);
balls_vals = data(2,:);
cubes = data(3,:);
cubes_vals = data(4,:);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just needed this: `fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
data = textscan(fid,'%s %f %s %f');
fclose(fid);
b=data{1,2};
c=data{1,4};
`